# How to remove the iframe body padding

Tags: javascript, iframe

ok i have bin struggling with this for quiet long nw...i am generating iframes dynamically using javascript...what im trying to do is to remove the default padding and margin and set it to 0px...heres my code

```
var newDiv = create_New_Div(); //this simple returns the id of the newly created
                           //div in javascript

        var iframeIdName="my"+inival_iframearea+"iframe";
        inival_iframearea++;
        var htcontents = "<iframe id='"+iframeIdName+"' frameborder='0'></iframe>";
        document.getElementById(newDiv).innerHTML = htcontents;
```

if i do like `<style> body {padding:0px; margin:0px} </style>` wat happens is that the main body has a zero padding and margin but when the iframe is generated after a user clicks a button, this style is not applied to the iframes body and has the default padding and margin which i donot want!!
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not loading anything in the iframe, you have to grab the document therein and make the changes yourself.

```
var
   iframe = document.getElementById(newDiv).getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

function restyle() {
   var body = iframe.contentDocument.body;
   body.style.padding = 0;
   body.style.margin = 0;
}

iframe.onload = restyle;
restyle();
```

There are some caveats with respect to `contentDocument`, so you may see weird behavior in different browsers.  Also, you may have trouble with accessing the document depending on how the browser interprets the lack of a `src` attribute.  I've seen issues where the calling page is https, and the lack of src leads the browser to load `about:blank`, which has a different protocol and thus violates the Same Origin Policy.

The reason for the `onload` is that even though you're not loading a separate page, the browser still has to load ''something'' in there.  YMMV.

Comment: Thank you so much jimbojw...its works perfect!! btw i dint use the "iframe.onLoad=restyle" line cauze there was sum error! wat did it do anyway?

Comment: The point of the onload is to handle the case where the browser hasn't finished "loading" the iframe yet.  Even though you don't specify a src attribute, the iframe still gets a document loaded in there, and you can't really count on it being done synchronously.